# Two drive ZFS pool, second drive overwritten with data. How do I restore/copy data back to the second drive?

Tags: zfs, drive, degraded

Data is intact in the first drive, second drive is "UNAVAIL". Reason for overwrite is my lack of concentration while applying dd command ...

Command

`sudo zpool replace -f hgst 4596995095197485503 /dev/sdd`

Gives

`invalid vdev specification
the following errors must be manually repaired:
/dev/sdd1 is part of active pool 'hgst'`

I took the disk offline and removed partitions with Gparted. After reboot they reappeared, and `zpool replace` -command did not work.

Command

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=1M count=2 seek=2048`

and

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=512 seek=$(( $(blockdev --getsz /dev/sdd) - 1 )) count=1
```

did not help either.

Command `sudo zpool labelclear /dev/sdd`
 and then `zpool replace` -command gave

```
cannot replace 4596995095197485503 with /dev/sdd: /dev/sdd is busy
```

Busy also with command

`sudo zpool replace -f hgst 4596995095197485503 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HDN724030ALE640_PK2238P3G3E0MJ`

[image: zpool status]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the disk offline

```
zpool offline hgst /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HDN724030ALE640_PK2238P3G3E0MJ
```

Detached the drive

`zpool detach hgst 4596995095197485503`

Cleared label

`zpool labelclear -f /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HDN724030ALE640_PK2238P3G3E0MJ`

Attached the disk back

`zpool attach hgst ata-HGST_HDN724030ALE640_PK2238P3G3E3UJ /dev/disk/by-id/ata-HGST_HDN724030ALE640_PK2238P3G3E0MJ`

And now it is resilvering.

```
NAME                                         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
hgst                                         ONLINE       0     0     0
  mirror-0                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
    ata-HGST_HDN724030ALE640_PK2238P3G3E3UJ  ONLINE       0     0     0
    ata-HGST_HDN724030ALE640_PK2238P3G3E0MJ  ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, it was a mirror, so it sure seems like you would just need to re-create the partition table and correctly sized partitions on the wiped disk, and the add it, then remove the left over entry.

This command would add a new device to the mirror

```
zpool add hgst mirror good_device_name new_device
```

And remove the old device

```
zpool remove hgst old_device_id
```

Or in a single step

```
zpool replace hgst old_device_id new_device
```

Links

- http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J/
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbcet/

P.S. Make sure that you have a good **verified** external backup, because you don't want to make things worse.

Comment: The add command would try to create a new vdev, you probably want attach and detach.

Answer (score 2):

I would use these commands:

```
zpool detach hgst <corrupted_device>
zpool attach -f hgst <online_device> <new_device>
```

(check `man pool` to be sure)

Use pool add carefully, because you easily end up with striped pool instead of a mirror!

Comment: Does this work if  <corrupted_device> and <new_device> are the same?